# Java Switch Statement to manipulate Enum case

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have the following segment of a java file:

```
Integer x; Integer y; Face facing;

enum Rotate { Clockwise, Anticlockwise };

enum Face { East, North, West, South };
```

and am having trouble figuring out how to implement a function to change the Face of an object (i.e. the direction that the object is facing).

The function begins as follows

```
private void rotateIt(Rotate rotateIt) {
    {
```

I have begun using the switch statement as follows ( below text is inside braces above ):

```
switch (facing)
case North  : ...?;
case West   : ...?;
case East   : ...?;
case South  : ...?;
```

I'd like to use the `Clockwise` enumeration to turn it from `East` to `South` etc. and `Anticlockwise` to do the reverse IYGWIM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
switch (facing) {
  case North  : facing=rotateIt==Rotate.Clockwise?Face.East:Face.West; break;
  case West   : facing=rotateIt==Rotate.Clockwise?Face.North:Face.South; break;
  case East   : facing=rotateIt==Rotate.Clockwise?Face.South:Face.North; break;
  case South  : facing=rotateIt==Rotate.Clockwise?Face.West:Face.East; break;
}
```

I should get a large percent of your grade retroactively!

Comment: @Grammin, There is something to say about terseness thought, especially when you're stuck repeating the same code over and over. I could save `rotateIt==Rotate.Clockwise` to a `bool` and use that, but that's not much of an improvement.

Comment: I think there's a way it could be simplified further.

Answer (score 2):

I would implement rotate as a function of the Face orientation:

```
 enum RotationDirection { Clockwise, CounterClockwise };
 enum Face {
    East, North, West, South ;

    Face rotate(RotationDirection direction ) {
        int tick  = (direction == RotationDirection.Clockwise)?-1:1;
        int index = this.ordinal()+tick ;
        int length = Face.values().length-1;
        if (index <0) index = length;
        if (index >length) index = 0;
        return Face.values()[index];
    }
```

Then you can do things like:

```
 Face face = Face.North;
 face.rotate(RotationDirection.Clockwise); // East
 face.rotate(RotationDirection.CounterClockwise); //West
```

This code makes use of the seldom used 'ordinal' property of Enums. It therefore requires that the values are in a logical turning order e.g. (east, north, west, south)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the enum to do the work.

```
enum Face { 
    North, East, South, West; // must be clockwise order.
}

enum Rotate { 
    private static final Face[] FACES = Face.values();
    Clockwise {
        public Face rotate(Face face) {
            return FACES[(ordinal()+1)%FACES.length];
        }
    }, 
    Anticlockwise {
        public Face rotate(Face face) {
            return FACES[(ordinal()+FACES.length-1)%FACES.length];
        }
    }
    public abstract Face rotate(Face face);
};

facing = rotateIt.rotate(facing);
```

Comment: IMO relying on `oridinal` is almost always a bad choice. I'd rather have faces be given numeric weights. Also, your implementation of `rotate` still has the `abstract` keyword. But definitely a better solution than the ones posted here, +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
case North:
{
  if(rotateIt == Rotate.Clockwise)
    facing = Face.EAST
  else
    facing = Face.WEST
  break;
}
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You are starting fine. Here is a more complete version of what you have to do regarding enum manipulation:

```
public void RotateIt(Rotate toRotate, Face facing) {

switch (facing) {
    case North:
        // Include code to rotate from north
        break;
    case West:
        // Include code to rotate from west
        break;
    case East:
        // Include code to rotate from east
        break;
    default: // South
        // Include code to rotate from south
        break;
}

}
```

Of course, this code could be optimized, but it gives you an idea of how to handle `enums` in `switch` statements.